# Embeding bokeh plot into a template (django)

Tags: django, bokeh

I'm trying to embed a bokeh plot into a template (home.html), but nothing is displayed after executing the code.
here's the code.

views.py (all packages are imported)

def home(request):

```
s = [1,4,6,8]
h = [1,5,9,8]

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600)
p.vbar(x=s, width=0.5, bottom=0,
       top=h, color="black")

script, div = components(p, CDN)
return render(request, 'home.html', {'div': div, 'script': script})
```

home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Experiment with Bokeh</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.1.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>

    {{ div|safe }}

    {{ script|safe }}


</body>
</html>
```

it displays nothing at the end, there's no error message, but and the page is completely blank

Help, Please!!

Comment: Bokeh 0.8.1 (which you're loading as a script in your html) is a pretty old release. Is there a reason you're using it and not something more current, like the newest 0.12.5 release?

Comment: Can you also open the browser developer console and see what error message may be there?

Comment: @LukeCanavan your version is working, I couldn't find, the latest one mentioned in the documentation is 0.12.0 .. the .5 is okay ;; THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading an ***ancient version*** of BokehJS from CDN:

```
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.1.min.css">
```

The 0.8.1 release is now *several years* old. By contrast, the `vbar` glyph method that you are using was only added quite recently. You need to make sure that the version of the BokehJS resources that you load in your template actually match the version of the Bokeh library that you are using.

Comment: I tried the version mentioned in the documentation (0.12.0), it ain't work neither, But 0.12.5 has worked perfectly. THANK YOU !!

Comment: The docs actually give a generic example: `<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-x.y.z.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` and then show `0.12.0` only as a *"for example, to use this one version"* But it's always the case that the versions need to match. If there is some way to make things clearer in the docs, please let us know.